# SOVLED Merge and get two collections with the same relationship

Tags: php, laravel

------ ADDED -------
It looks like a bulletin board.
Users can create "channels" and
You can enter "Channel" and write "Post"
From here.
The "channel" I created is
It will be entered into the channels model
When I join a "channel" created by someone else, I enter the    channels_joins model.

Simply
in the channel model
Information such as channel name, creator, etc.
Channel joins model contains only channel_id and user_id, and each id    is connected with a foreigner key.

I combine the "channels" I created and the "channels" I subscribed to in the view and show them as a list
The code is below

```
        $joins = $this->channelJoins()
            ->join('channels', 'channel_joins.channel_id', '=', 'channels.id')
            ->get();
        $channels = $this->channels()
            ->leftJoin('channel_joins', 'channels.id', '=', 'channel_joins.channel_id')
            ->select('channels.*', 'channel_joins.channel_id', 'channel_joins.user_id')
            ->get();
        $vals = collect($joins)->merge($channels);
```

I need to iterate over the list in the view and show two data.

1. Show channel name
2. Number of people who are subscribed to the channel

Here's why I'm stuck
When checked with dd(), $list consists of one collection, and there are two models "App\Models\Channels" and "App\Models\Channel_joins" in it.

[image]

In the case of a channel model, the channel name is not a problem, but the problem is to print the number of people who are subscribed.
In case of channel joins model, it is a problem to output the channel name.

I

```
            @forelse ($posts as $list)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="p-1 ml-1">
                            <a href="{{ route('channel.show', $list->id) }}">{{ $list->name }}</a>
                            <p class="float-right">
                                Count:&nbsp;
                                <span class="total">
{{--                                    {{ dd($list) }}--}} 
                                    {{ ($list->count('user_id')) }}
                                </span>
                                &nbsp; EA
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

------ ADDED ---------

Here is

```
Channels Table
```

[image]

```
Channel Joins Table
```

[image]

```
Users Table
```

[image]

Thanks for reply
I have one channel called a, but in the picture, it is output as two.

In addition, the number of people who are subscribed to channel a is 2, and the other channels have 0-1 people. In the picture, the wrong value is exposed.

how to modify my query to right way ?

[image]

Comment: add some of your trying along with specific problem within the things you tried.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand how should i do ?

Comment: 1. how do you want to combine them? as a single collection? or like the way you merged two model instances?

Comment: another thing is not clear. what are rooms? channels are rooms or a channel hasMany rooms? it is not clear in your question. please describe them

Comment: What does the `dd()` show of `$vals/$list` (I assume they are the same thing). Have you tried a `foreach` in the view and if so how does it fail?

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I Edit my Post

Comment: You said 'it is a problem to output the channel name'. What is the problem, is there an error? I tried reproducing your situation with the code you provided and it works fine.

Comment: I edit my post and add my model values

Comment: you can use belongs to many relationship in the channel model and then you can count subscribers from channel joins

Comment: Yes,
In case of channel model
As you said, it can be calculated with the count and sum functions.
How do I calculate the value for the channel_joins model?
I have a view counting subscribers in one way, can I modify the query accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I fix it
Thanks all

ps.
I don't speak English, so I guess I couldn't convey the problem accurately.
Sorry and thank you to everyone who responded.

```
        $joins = Channel::whereHas('channelJoins', function($q) use ($userId) {
            $q->where('user_id', $userId);
        })
            ->get();
        $channels = Channel::where('user_id', $userId)
            ->with('channelJoins')
            ->get();
        $vals = collect($joins)->merge($channels);
```

```
{{ $list->channelJoins->count() }}
```